SQL explode records that have overlapping date ranges
I have a SQL table containing rental contracts for cars, each with a start date and an end date. Some contracts referencing the same car have overlapping date ranges, and I'm seeking advice on how to clean this data effectively.
Here's a simplified example of the input data:



contract_id
car_id
start_date
end_date




aaa
123
2024-03-01
2024-06-30


bbb
123
2024-02-15
2024-03-15


ccc
123
2024-06-15
2024-07-15


ddd
123
2024-04-01
2024-04-05


eee
123
2024-12-01
2024-12-01



I want to clean this data by exploding the records, giving priority to the shortest contracts. The desired output would be:



contract_id
car_id
start_date
end_date




bbb
123
2024-02-15
2024-03-15


aaa
123
2024-03-16
2024-03-31


ddd
123
2024-04-01
2024-04-05


aaa
123
2024-04-06
2024-06-14


ccc
123
2024-06-15
2024-07-15


eee
123
2024-12-01
2024-12-01



in this example aaa, bbb and ccc are overlapping in different ways. To lose as little information as possible, I gave priority to the shorter contracts, thus partitioning the longest (aaa) into smaller fractions distributed along its duration, but in a way such as it is not overlapping with any of the others.
Here is a graphical representation:

I tried to implement this by making use of lag, lead and row_number but with little success, I'm also open to alternative solutions or suggestions.
If you want you can use these insert statements:
INSERT INTO Contracts (contract_id, car_id, start_date, end_date)
VALUES
    ('aaa', 123, '2024-03-01', '2024-06-30'),
    ('bbb', 123, '2024-02-15', '2024-03-15'),
    ('ccc', 123, '2024-06-15', '2024-07-15'),
    ('ddd', 123, '2024-04-01', '2024-04-05'),
    ('eee', 456, '2024-12-01', '2024-12-01');

I'd appreciate any feedback. Thanks in advance for your help!

Maybe we could use this fiddle to collaborate on a solution https://dbfiddle.uk/mSqZDDiC

Identify contracts to split to resolve overlap https://dbfiddle.uk/4Jf_F52P

I think I did it, but it is a very long process https://dbfiddle.uk/78xGbDR7

I changed all the CTEs to temp tables to see what it was doing. Yes, it is alot of records to deal with.  Your solution should work well enough for small datatsets. https://dbfiddle.uk/g6unXzyb

unfortunately I do have a big dataset…
